# AWS CodeDeploy export database credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, aws-code-deploy, aws-codebuild

I have a SpringBoot application, which connects to Amazon RDS. Naturally there is a property file which contains the database connection details.

I have AWS Codepipeline which is my CI/CD and everything works as expected.

However, I am trying to not hard code the database credentials in the properties file because it lives in the source repository.

I would like to have placeholders in the properties file and then replace them from environment variables during the deploy phase.

**What I am thinking?**

1. I probably can set the environment variables like DB_USERNAME etc somewhere in AWS (I need clarity here)
2. Somehow in the codedeploy (after-install) phase I can use those variables and use sed to replace the values in the properties file.

Please point me in the right direction. I know there are a lot of experts with many good suggestions. My goal right now is to find the easiest solution.

PS: I am aware of the IAM DB Authentication but I don't want to go that route for now. May be in future.

Comment: Probably good idea would be to use parameter store or secrets manager to keep the db credentails, and the reference them in your CD hook scripts.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin , your comment pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: No problem. Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a solution like `confd` [1] which can get secrets from aws parameter store natively and update templatized config files. Much cleaner solution and seperates the concern from CodeDeploy deployment.

[1] https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd

Comment: thanks! I guess this is far more complicated solution. I already got it working by doing the replacements in the build process. That is much cleaner for my usecase